# Module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'

Tags: c++, qt, msbuild

I'm trying to compile a C++ program that depends on Qt 5.9.1 modules and got the following error message:

```
Qt5Widgets.lib(Qt5Widgets.dll) : fatal error LNK1112:
module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'
```

I'm using command line MSBuild (from Visual Studio Community 2017) on Windows 10 x64. As I learn from previous questions the problem seem to be that the Qt 5.9.1 modules are x64 where as the MSBuild assume that my program is x86. I've tried the most proposed solutions of running the compilation on the `Developer Command Prompt`, `x64 Native Tools Command Prompt`, `x64_x86 Cross Tools Command Prompt`, `x86 Native Tools Command Prompt` and `x86_x64 Cross Tools Command Prompt`. None of these works, and I still get the same error message. I'm not using the Visual Studio IDE, just the MSBuild on the command line with CMake and generator set to "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64". I also learns that there is no known way to explicitly instruct MSBuild to do x64 build. Is there any other way to solve this? I'm missing something from previous answers? Is there a way to enforce this in CMake?

Comment: ***Is there a way to enforce this in CMake?*** Select the correct generator. Make sure the command prompt that you used matches the binaries. I mean if Qt is 32 bit don't use the x86_x64 command prompt. You probably need to clean your build folder and regenerate after you get the correct command prompt. Also make sure CMake found the correct version of Qt and not some other version of Qt you have installed.

Comment: Did you set `/p:Platform=x64` in msbuild command line?

Comment: @ikleschenkov, that seem to be a feature that was available in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: @drescherjm. the generator is correct, I have done cleaning several times without success. I know of the correct command prompt, out of frustration I tried all others too.

Comment: Then your best bet is to use the "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" generator and cmake --build . after you clean the build folder and regenerate again. That way you don't have to deal with broken / inconsistent compiler settings.

Comment: *MSBuild assume that my program is x86* I'm not sure that is an accurate explanation of what happens: msbuild does what it's told, e.g. what ikleschenkov mentions works for standard project files, also in VS2017. So if you get this linker error, it's because the project file, possibly in combination with the command prompt used, doesn't do everything as one would expect. Then again, hard to guess since we cannot see the project file..